# Mapping Outbound IPs to 1 IP in Azure App Services

Tags: azure, networking

I have 3 components of my architecture running in 3 separate Azure App Services. Each app service has 4 outbound IPs. So whenever I have to deploy my app onto the client's premise, I have to whitelist 12-16 IPs on their on-premise Firewall.

Is there any way I can deploy a NAT which uses only 1 public IP and I can provide just 1 IP to the client?

If I manage to make this architecture work then how would I modify my API calls to these services, since at the moment I'm using their 1 public IP to access their individual service, with just 1 IP how will I distinguish API calls made to different app service.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Application Gateway allows you to provide one public IP for those App Services.

You have to make the following steps:

1. Provision Application Gateway
2. Add listeners with host name for eachof the App Services
3. Add backends for each of the App Service
4. Create HTTP Settings with *Override with new host name* and *Pick host name from backend target* options
5. Add rules to connect listeners corresponding to backends

At the end customer has to white-list one public IP assigned to Application Gateway and create DNS entries to point all App Services addresses to one public IP.

Materials:

- [Application Gateway support for multi-tenant back ends such as App
  service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-overview)
- [How an application gateway works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works)